# Adding Image to a Polygon

Tags: java, swing

I have been looking around to for help with this and no luck so I thought I would ask.

I am creating a series of diamond polygons and want to add an image onto them but tried drawing onto them and it hasnt worked.

Any suggestions on how this can be done.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try?  What didn't work?

Comment: A polygon isn't really something onto which you can draw an image.  You will want a canvas or something more general like that.  A polygon is just a shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/TexturePaint.html

Answer (score 3):

```
graphics.setClip( Shape );
graphics.drawImage(...);
```